# How can i reference to element which calls a jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery

For example:

```
<div id="target" data-width="400px"></div>

$("#target").myPlugin({width: ??? });
```

??? must be `data-width` attribute value.

Comment: `$("#target").myPlugin({width: $("#target").data('width') });`

Comment: '$("#target").myPlugin({width: $("#target").attr('width') });'

Comment: @adeneo you should make this an answer

Comment: @NullPointer - It's sunday, so no work, and all answers in comments ;-) ...

Comment: @NullPointer - sure, go ahead.

Comment: @behrouzvb you have already done

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#target").myPlugin({width: $("#target").attr('data-width') });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by

```
$("#target").myPlugin({
  width: $("#target").data('width') 
 });
```

all credit goes to [adeneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965051/adeneo)

Comment: thanks. how can i do this for more than one element? $("#target1,#target2").myPlugin(....)

Comment: Could you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/width/

You can easyly get leh width with .width()